# How to write a unique dictionary within dictionary with list as keys to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary, in which each key has one unique dictionary as its value.  Now the value for each of these keys is a list.  For example:

```
d = {'date1': {'name1': [1, 2], 'name2': [2, 4, 2]}, 'date2': {'name1': [4, 5, 6]}}
```

My goal is to write this dictionary to csv files.  I would like to have the file name be the key values of the outer dictionary (date1.csv, date2.csv), where each of these files have the inner dictionary keys as columns with the values going down the columns.  Using our example:

```
date1.csv

name1    name2
1        2
2        4
         2
```

I have tried to loop through the outer dictionary, open a csv file with the name of this key to write, but I cannot figure out how to manage making the lists as values in the columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity use `pandas`

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'date1': {'name1': [1, 2], 'name2': [2, 4, 2]}, 'date2': {'name1': [4, 5, 6]}} 

for filename in d:
    df = pd.DataFrame({key:pd.Series(value) for key, value in d[filename].items() })
    df.to_csv(filename+'.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a fun one.

```
import itertools

d = {'date1': {'name1': [1, 2], 'name2': [2, 4, 2]}, 'date2': {'name1': [4, 5, 6]}} 

for k,v in d.items():
    with open(k+'.csv','w') as fout:
        print( ','.join(v.keys()), file=fout)
        for cols in itertools.zip_longest(*v.values()):
            cols = ['' if i is None else str(i) for i in cols]
            print( ','.join(cols), file=fout )
```

```
[timr@Tims-Pro:~/src]$ python x.py
[timr@Tims-Pro:~/src]$ cat date1.csv 
name1,name2
1,2
2,4
,2
[timr@Tims-Pro:~/src]$ cat date2.csv
name1
4
5
6
[timr@Tims-Pro:~/src]$
```